# Как конвертировать PDF в PNG в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, конвертация

Пробовал так:

```
convert p5.pdf output-%3d.jpg
```

Ошибка:

> convert-im6.q16: not authorized `p5.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412. convert-im6.q16: no images defined` output-%3d.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.

И вот так:

```
pdftoppm -png p5.pdf imagen
```

Ошибка:

> Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
> Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
> Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
> Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
> --
> Все попытки внутри каталога с pdf-файлом.

Comment: Видимо файл битый.

Comment: @Alex Alex, обалдеть, но это оказалось правдой! Залил проверенный pdf и он сконвертировался! Спасибо!